# How can I block return button?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I need to block return button

```
private void MainPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{ 
    //?
}
```

And then I need to unblock it. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the back-button from actually navigating back, just cancel the event:

```
e.Cancel = true;
```